Identify the openshift pod/deployment from which an http request came to another pod
I have a service that is deployed in openshift.
There is a specific http request that is only allowed to come from one specific other service, also deployed in openshift.
When I get the http request, what would be the best way to make sure it came from the other service and not someone else? (Has to be secure)

Can you use a service account token, or provision your own TLS client certificates?

Check if network policies can help out

If you want to restrict the traffic generated within the cluster then Network Policy is the way to go.
